# Firebase getIdToken returns object

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, redux-saga

I am using [redux-saga](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/introduction/BeginnerTutorial.html) and [redux-saga-firebase](https://github.com/n6g7/redux-saga-firebase) library to integrate [firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/) with redux-sagas. The problem is when I sign in a user, for example with `signInWithEmailAndPassword` and even connect `channel` to get the signed user and track user changes, I am not able to get correct token. `getIdToken`, `getIdTokenResult` methods just return objects with the following representation:

```
{
    a: 0
    b: qb {a: null, g: ƒ, b: ƒ, f: undefined, next: null, …}
    c: A {a: 0, i: undefined, c: A, b: qb, f: qb, …}
    f: qb {a: null, g: ƒ, b: ƒ, f: undefined, next: null, …}
    g: false
    h: false
    i: undefined
}
```

And here is the code:

```
function* loginSaga({ payload: { email, password } }) {
    try {
        yield call(
            reduxSagaFirebase.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword,
            email,
            password,
        );
    } catch (error) {
        yield put(loginFailure(error));
    }
}

function* loginStatusWatcher() {
    const channel = yield call(reduxSagaFirebase.auth.channel);

    while (true) {
        const { user } = yield take(channel);
        if (user) {
            yield put(loginSuccess());
        } else {
            console.log('Put logout action here');
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 4):

getIdToken returns a promise, make sure you use `getIdToken().then((token) => console.log(token))`